# ReCAPTCHA v3 Google Badge is drawn underneath page content

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha-v3

Please visit this page:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/contact-form/

Ideally please use a small phone like an iPhone6s. Scroll down to the bottom:

[image: Badge overwrite]

I know how to identify certain controls and set their Z index to 0 and thus the badge draw over them, but it will be a nightmare to add such settings for everything.

Instead, is there a way to do the reverse? Can I get this badge to ensure it is drawn on top of the page content?

The issue is worse if you scroll to the very bottom on a PC. You hover the mouse over the badge and it displays UNDERNEATH the footer area.

I have tried this:

```
body:not(.page-id-833) .grecaptcha-badge {
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}
```

No joy.

Comment: Hi so you want to set the style tyo the badge right

Comment: so the badge is always ontop?

Comment: @GarthBaker Yes, that is what I want. Just like the "Scroll to Top" behaviour.

Comment: Hi did you try the code I sent you

Comment: @GarthBaker Yes. If I remove `body:not(.page-id-833) ` from my CSS then it works. But this means the badge shows for all pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you set the badge to display none. The just set it to display as a block on the page you want it to show on using important to override the first style. :)

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
   display:none;
}
.page-id-833 .grecaptcha-badge {
   z-index: 99999;
   display:block !important;
}
```

As for the high z-index. It's just what worked on the site you provided.
If you have issues and it only works on some of your pages. Just add !important to your stylesheet.

Comment: Please see updated question. I also tried with `!important`.

Comment: Ok, using this `z-index` is fine if I do not try to hide the badge on all but page 833.

Answer (score -1):

```
function PageLoad() {           // find div which is blocking the page.
  var t = $('div').filter(function ()
  {
  var self = $(this);
  return self.css('z-index') == '2000000000' && self.css('opacity') == '0.05' && 
         self.css('left') == '0px' && self.css('top') == '0px' &&  
         self.css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  }
  );
  if (t.css("visibility") != "hidden") {
    t.css("visibility", "");
    t.css("visibility", "hidden");
    t.css("position", "absolute");
  }
}
$(document).ready(function () {  // Chrome browser is okay with window.onload but IE was not.
                                 // so I used thie way.
                                 // when user hover on 'body' or click.
                                 // blocking div will be modified.
  $("body").hover(function () {
    PageLoad();
  });
  $("body").click(function() {
    PageLoad();
  });
  $(document).on('vclick',function(){
    PageLoad();
  });
  $(document).on("tap",function(){
    PageLoad();
  });
});
```